# abs() not working on Xcode?

Tags: c, xcode

I'm getting incorrect values from the standard library abs(). 
In the example below, min  & max are correctly evaluated as  -18635 and 3402, and yet absMax is resulting in 3402, so it should be 18635. Should this work, or I have made a mistake?

```
double    NormalizeWaveData(SInt16 *inData, long inlength)
{
    int maxAmp = 0, minAmp=0, absMax=0;
    for(long i=0; i<inlength; i++)
    {
        if( inData[i] > maxAmp)
           maxAmp = inData[i];
        if( inData[i] < minAmp)
           minAmp = inData[i];

        if( abs(inData[i]) > absMax)
           absMax = inData[i];

    }
...
```

Comment: Is this C, C++ or Objective-C ? Also, where are you getting your definition of `abs` from (i.e. is it a custom definition or are you getting it from a standard library header) ?

Comment: Xcode is an IDE, please retag with correct language as asked by Paul R

Comment: @CRDave: Please read your comment *problem is of datatype abs is for int so may not work for int* Is this you wanted to say...!!!

Comment: MAy be problem is of datatype abs is for int so may not work for SInt16. @Anoop thanks.

Comment: SInt16 is typedef of signed short int, I dont think this will be a problem. But as you can say in his code he compared after abs() and forgot to store abs()-ed value to absMax.

Comment: @Zaph. Apologies, see "or I have made a mistake?"

Comment: @Joey It would help you to learn what Xcode is, what libraries are and consider that if it looks like some fundamental thing were broken that the whole of iOS could not work. Just the mind-set of first assuming that I made a mistake goes a long way toward my solving my problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use

```
if( abs(inData[i]) > absMax)
       absMax = abs(inData[i]);
```

Comment: More explanation: you set absMax to -18635 (and not the `abs()` value), then when evaluated for 3402, that is bigger.

Comment: @cjk: Exactly. I mentioned same as a comment above, but forgot to mention here :)

Comment: Note also that calculating `absMax` in the loop is rather redundant - you might as well just do it once after the loop has completed, e.g. `absMax = max(maxAmp, -minAmp);`